# Publication List association for Salesforce Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, publicationlist

How can I associate an email send to a Publication list for a Salesforce send? I can do it in Journey and User-Initiated emails, but I don't seen an option when I create a Salesforce Send?

[image: Journey]
[image: User-Initiated]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_marketing_cloud_sends_to_campaigns_or_reports.htm&type=5), you can only use Salesforce Send with Salesforce Reports, Campaigns, or Data Extensions.

Salesforce Sends are always associated with the All Subscribers list and thus people got unsubed fully.